# "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"? in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I try to run MySQL server on XAMPP but I get the following error message:

```
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 300387; transaction id 170
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2022-05-15 16:06:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I just installed MySQL Workbench and I think i am using the port 3306 there so I think that that's the issue but I don't know what to do about it